# Как переиспользовать код функции

Tags: python, ооп

Очень не хочу дублировать код.

Есть две функции в разных классах, они отличаются только дополнительным значением в словаре:

```
def recursive_node_to_dict(self, node):
    result = {
        'id': node.pk,
        'name': node.name,
        'description': node.description,
        'code': node.code,
        'level': node.level,            
    }
    children = [self.recursive_node_to_dict(c) for c in node.get_children()]
    if children:
        result['children'] = children
    return result

def recursive_node_to_dict(self, node):
    result = {
        'id': node.pk,
        'name': node.name,
        'description': node.description,
        'code': node.code,
        'level': node.level,
        'parent': node.parent_id
    }
    children = [self.recursive_node_to_dict(c) for c in node.get_children()]
    if children:
        result['children'] = children
    return result
```

Вызываю так:

```
class ProductApplicabilitiesList(APIView):

    def get (self, request):
        root_nodes = cache_tree_children(ProductApplicabilities.objects.all())
        dicts = []
        for n in root_nodes:
            dicts.append(self.recursive_node_to_dict(n))
        return Response(dicts)
```

Как, без костылей, убрать дублирование кода, передавая разный словарь в параметрах функции и переиспользовать ее?

Пробовал, вот так:

```
def recursive_node_to_dict(node, id,name,code,level,parent):
    result = {id,name,code,level,parent}
    children = [recursive_node_to_dict(c) for c in node.get_children()]
    if children:
        result['children'] = children
    return result

class ProductCategoryList(APIView):
    """Категории продуктов"""

    def get(self, request):
        root_nodes = cache_tree_children(ProductCategory.objects.all())
        dicts = []
        for n in root_nodes:
            result = {
                'node': n,
                'id': n.pk,
                'name': n.name,
                'code': n.code,
                'level': n.level,
                'parent': n.parent_id
            }
            dicts.append(recursive_node_to_dict(**result))
        return Response(dicts)
```

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: recursive_node_to_dict() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'id', 'name', 'code', 'level', and 'parent'
```

Comment: у вас в последнем предложении содержится ответ на вопрос.

Comment: да это понятно, как это сделать - вот в чём вопрос.

Comment: сделайте родителя, от которого наследуются оба класса

Comment: @Интик, это на любителя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recursive_node_to_dict(c)` -- передается только `node`

Comment: Только сейчас понял о чем вы) Но если я передаю два параметра children = [recursive_node_to_dict(c, result) for c in node.get_children()] у меня случается ValueError: Circular reference detected

Comment: Если у функции 6 параметров при описании, то и при вызове 6. Сучетом `**`